# VueJS Axios request to API generate the multiple same params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, vue.js, axios

Trying to create VueJS Axios request to API (rails backend) and get duplication of parameters in the request.
My vue request to server:

```
onlogin () {
       axios.post('http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in', {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
      })
```

In the terminal see:

```
Started OPTIONS "/auth/sign_in" for ::1 at 2019-09-10 23:03:02 +0300
Started POST "/auth/sign_in" for ::1 at 2019-09-10 23:03:02 +0300
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"mail@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"mail@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameter: :session
Unpermitted parameter: :session
```

This request from Postman is OK:

```
Started POST "/auth/sign_in?email=mail@mail.com&password=[FILTERED]" for ::1 at 2019-09-10 23:05:09 +0300
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"mail@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

Any idea why the :session parameters is added to request?

Comment: Have you responded to the browser (axios) with a cookie and stored something in a session which is now showing up in a new request? Does the same parameter appear if you test in an incognito browser window?

Comment: Do you have a global interceptor which adds this? Look for `axios.interceptors.request.use` in your code base.